# Python: Create list from function that returns single item or another list

Tags: python, list

(Python 3.5).

**Problem Statement:** Given a function that returns either an item or a list of items, is there a single line statement that would initialize a new list from the results of calling the aforementioned function?

**Details:** I've looked at the documents on python lists, and tried some things out on the repl, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

I'm calling a third party function that reads an xml document. The function sometimes returns a list and sometimes returns a single item (depending on how many xml entries exist).

For my purposes, I always need a list that I can iterate over - even if it is a length of one. The code below correctly accomplishes what I desire. Given Python's elegance, however, it seems clunky. I suspect there is a single-line way of doing it.

```
def force_list(item_or_list):
    """
    Returns a list from either an item or a list.
    :param item_or_list: Either a single object, or a list of objects
    :return: A list of objects, potentially with a length of 1.
    """
    if item_or_list is None: return None
    _new_list = []
    if isinstance(item_or_list, list):
        _new_list.extend(item_or_list)
    else:
        _new_list.append(item_or_list)
    return _new_list
```

Thanks in advance, 
SteveJ

Comment: `[item] if not isiinstance(item, list) else item`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget you should add that as an answer ;)

Comment: Can you please specify what is the single items type? Is it a string, or an integer, etc....

Comment: @inspectorG4dget  that was fast! Thanks. Is this question worthy of keeping alive for others to see or should I delete it?

Comment: I'd think so, that's a nice looking piece of code.

Comment: This is a pretty common thing that people seem to like -- unfortunately I've found that this shortcut frequently ends up biting me in the end.  It's much better if you _know_ the (properties of the) type that you're passing to the function and pass a `list` if the function wants a `list` (rather than trying to make the function behave overly polymorphic).

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Clearly you had the answer, if you want to add it below as an answre I'll give it the nod. Otherwise, I'll edit my post with the answer that you gave.

Comment: @SteveJ: I've already added it. Check it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for a one-liner about listifying the result of a function call:

Let's say there's a function called `func` that returns either an item or a list of items:

```
elem = func()
answer = elem if isinstance(elem, list) else [elem]
```

That being said, you should really refactor `func` to return one type of thing - make it return a list of many elements, or in the case that it returns only one element, make it return a list with that element. Thus you can avoid such type-checking

Comment: If you'd like to be able to do this to _any_ iterable, you could use `import collections; isinstance(elem, collections.Iterable)` instead.

Comment: I'll cast my vote for this one because of the last paragraph -- Functions should return only a single type of object (and _possibly_ `None`, but even that one I prefer to avoid in most cases).

Comment: Thanks again. The function call is to a third party library. My function is a wrapper - and it only returns the list or None.

Comment: ...btw, shouldn't you get rid of the 'not' in the statement above?

Answer (score 1):

You may check it like in one line as:

```
 if item: # Check whether it is not None or empty list
     # Check if it is list. If not, append it to existing list after converting it to list
     _new_list.extend(item if isiinstance(item, list) else [item])
```

Comment: You probably want `[item]` -- `list(1)` won't produce a list :-)

Comment: @mgilson: That's true. Updated it :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this in a single line is

```
def force_list(item_or_list=[]):
    return item_or_list if type(item_or_list) is list else [item_or_list]
```

print force_list("test")

> test

print force_list(["test","test2"])

> ["test","test2"]